# Don't increment # of views from the same account by more than 1?

Tags: feature-request, views

Displaying the questions page on Stack Overflow using the score filter shows [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array) as the first result. The displayed number of views is "1.8m". That question is viewed by registered and non-registered users.

To reflect a more realistic view count, restrict the counter from incrementing more than once when it is viewed by registered users.

Comment: Why would that be more realistic?

Comment: Because it would show closely how many unique individuals viewed the question @Dharman

Comment: @machine_1 it never claims to be "viewed by N people", it says "Viewed N times". In which case the current implementation is more accurate.

Comment: So, why should it not count my view if I come back to the question 2 years later?

Comment: Also, the overhead of tracking _who_ viewed _what_ is... Oof, massive.

Comment: I think you are like all of us: you google your best keywords to get that SO question from where you copy the code, and you do this all the time with the same question. So it's helpful for the same person more than one time

Comment: There exists no reliable way to count unique visitors. The view count doesn't try to achieve this impossible task. It only shows how many times the page has been opened. It doesn't matter how many people actually have seen it.

Comment: I said "more realistic view count" not "counting all unique visitors" ...

Comment: @Cerbrus, fortunately it is *massive*, otherwise the current SE administration would probably both have done and sold that already.

Comment: @machine_1 SE would have to keep track of every singe user <-> page view relation. That's way too much overhead for very little gain. That table would get insanely large insanely quick, and would need to be counted on __every question page load for every single user__.

Comment: Currently, multiple anonymous views from the same IP address within 15 minutes and multiple views from the same logged in user within 15 minutes only increase the view count by 1. It would be quite expensive to keep a list *for every question* of the user ID for *every user who ever viewed the question*. That doesn't seem reasonable. It would, as @AbdulAzizBarkat says, also be a major change to the metric, requiring a change to the displayed wording and make the data from over the last decade+ significantly different from the data moving forward.

Comment: I actually support this 'Feature Request', I also find the 'Viewed # times' metric not realistic and nearly annoying, where for example in the small Tag I answer/follow, for some Questions I am following/checking regularly, (usually because I answered or posted a Comment), I sometimes account just by myself for [50%-75%] for the total 'Viewed # times' metric. // Same also for the '# profile views' metric on a User's Profile. // I would prefer that [same User-Logon / same IP / same Session-ID (within 24h)] (15 min is too short) would only count for 1 View.

Comment: Related/reference: [answer to: "Views indicator inaccurate, shows one views on question with two close votes"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80857/271271), "[How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/271271)", and "[Does the number of views on an SO question exclude my own views?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122169/271271)"

Comment: @chivracq Profiles no longer display # of profile views, right?

Comment: Oh...!, then I get the '# of profile views' from a Userscript, (+ the exact 'Last seen' info which is the "real" info I'm interested in, to "assess" the Follow-up of Askers when I comment/answer on their Qt)... I just mentioned that Field because it behaves like the '# of views' Indicator..., then, forget about it, keep focusing on the '# of views'...

Answer (score 12):

> To reflect a more realistic view count, restrict the counter from incrementing more than once when it is viewed by registered users.

How would that be a more realistic ***VIEW count***? If I viewed a SO page 5 times in the course of, say, a year* - how would it be realistic if the **views** count is 1?

Apart from the technical difficulties raised in the comments above, I just don't see the need for the views count to be unique per user. *"[It never claimed to be "viewed by N people", it says "Viewed N times"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425347/dont-increment-of-views-from-the-same-account-by-more-than-1#comment963490_425347)"*.

---

<sub>* As [Makyen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3773011/makyen) [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425347/dont-increment-of-views-from-the-same-account-by-more-than-1#comment963498_425347), multiple views in a time frame of 15 minutes do not count so I used a larger time frame to indicate that I visit a certain page multiple times for an actual need over time.</sub>